# Design patterns - Separate classes difference in constructor only

Tags: php, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Question to the design patterns junkies out there, because we've been having a team argument over this for far longer than we should.

So we use a framework, `Yii2`, that creates default models for the database tables. In one example, table `t_receipt_settings` has the model `TReceiptSettings`. Because we have some default settings, one approach to carry those default settings was to create another class `DefaultReceiptSettings` that extends `TReceiptSettings` with only a different constructor. Example:

```
class DefaultReceiptSettings extends TReceiptSettings
{
    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        $this->print_website_address = 1;
        $this->print_email_address = 1;
        $this->print_phone_no = 1;
        $this->print_cash_reg_name = 1;
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

}
```

Now the reviews that this method collected were either:

1. This is WRONG. You should create a static method in `TReceiptSettings` that sets the defaults for you. OR
2. This is a CORRECT approach. Creating a new class with initial defaults is in fact favorable. Having in your code elsewhere new `DefaultReceiptSettings();` is much better than the alternative.

Is this a good solution? an acceptable solution? or a wrong solution? And why?

Comment: Assuming you've generated the models with Gii, it's almost always better to extend them since classes representing database tables change if your table structure changes. If you're working on the base class directly, you'll be unable to use Gii to generate any changes. So 2 would be the correct approach in my experience

Comment: Having multiple models for the same underlying entity feels wrong imo. This is not necessarily an object oriented problem but more of a ORM problem.

Comment: What does these settings consists of? Just default values to some of the fields or?

Comment: @BrettGregson ohh okk. Good idea. But actually if we're following your approach I would say that approach 2 would involve having 3 models then. One for the database, one that extends it that we would be using say ReceiptSettings and again a third DefaultReceiptSettings. What would you say about this approach?

Comment: @MartinDimitrov exactly. We have a default settings object that we create for each new client, if he did not add any object. So according to some in the team, the best place to store those settings, instead of leaving them lying around in the code was to create a separate model for them

Comment: Is there a reason, why you cannot put these settings in the `rules()` function?

Comment: mmm @MartinDimitrov this is actually not a very bad idea. I like it. 
Not sure if this is the best solution here though since we either have the default object with all its values, or we take the values from the user. Its either this complete object or nothing sort of. Will definitely vouch for your idea though and start using it, never tried this before

Comment: This is the standard approach for anything like this. Glad you like it :)